# 3D- Analysis: Calculate the 3D trajectory distance considering a set of points below the sea level issue

Tags: arcgis-pro, distance, elevation, 3d-analyst

I am trying to calculate the 3D trajectory distance considering a set of points below sea level. I've opted for creating a 2D line that considers the 2D trajectory of the points and then interpolate this line with a surface raster and then add Z values. The TIN and Raster surfaces come out great with the correct elevation, then I interpolate de 2D line with the surface raster and then add Z values. It gives a 3D length value, but when I create the elevation profile for the 3D line, it doesn't take any elevation values from it. This leads me to believe that the 3D distance calculation might be incorrect.

[image: Image below of result]